# Issue with androidx CursorLoader

Tags: java, android, android-contentprovider

I am trying to implement a Content Provider on my application.

**Expected behavior:** At the end of the method createLoaderCourses(), returning a CursorLoader should lead me to the method called "query" on the Content Provider.

**Actual behavior:** The method createLoaderCourses() directly returns a null value without calling the "query" method of the content provider.

Below is the method that returns null instead of the CursorLoader.

```java
private CursorLoader createLoaderCourses() {
        mCoursesQueryFinished = false;
        Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://com.example.notekeeper.provider");
        String[] courseColumns = {
                CourseInfoEntry.COLUMN_COURSE_TITLE,
                CourseInfoEntry.COLUMN_COURSE_ID,
                CourseInfoEntry._ID
        };
        return new CursorLoader(this, uri, courseColumns, null, null, CourseInfoEntry.COLUMN_COURSE_TITLE);
    }
```

And here is my provider class:

```java
package com.example.notekeeper;

import android.content.ContentProvider;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.net.Uri;

import com.example.notekeeper.NoteKeeperDatabaseContract.CourseInfoEntry;

public class NoteKeeperProvider extends ContentProvider {

    private NoteKeeperOpenHelper mDbOpenHelper;

    public NoteKeeperProvider() {
    }

    @Override
    public int delete(Uri uri, String selection, String[] selectionArgs) {
        // Implement this to handle requests to delete one or more rows.
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
    }

    @Override
    public String getType(Uri uri) {
        // TODO: Implement this to handle requests for the MIME type of the data
        // at the given URI.
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
    }

    @Override
    public Uri insert(Uri uri, ContentValues values) {
        // TODO: Implement this to handle requests to insert a new row.
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreate() {
        mDbOpenHelper = new NoteKeeperOpenHelper(getContext());
        return true;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param uri
     * @param projection Columns that we want to select
     * @param selection
     * @param selectionArgs
     * @param sortOrder
     * @return
     */
    @Override
    public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection,
                        String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = mDbOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.query(CourseInfoEntry.TABLE_NAME, projection, selection, selectionArgs,
                null, null, sortOrder);
        return cursor;
    }

    @Override
    public int update(Uri uri, ContentValues values, String selection,
                      String[] selectionArgs) {
        // TODO: Implement this to handle requests to update one or more rows.
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. I guess that in earlier versions of Android, when a provider is built, the AndroidManifest.xml file looks like this:

```
 <provider
     android:name=".NoteKeeperProvider"
     android:authorities="com.yourproject.package.provider"
     android:enabled="true"
     android:exported="true"></provider>
```

But mine was like this:

```
 <provider
     android:name=".NoteKeeperProvider"
     android:authorities="com.yourproject.package"
     android:enabled="true"
     android:exported="true"></provider>
```

So, my URI value was wrong. If you have a similar issue, check that your URI matchs the provider authorities value in the manifest xml file.